# fetching property from another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties, viewcontroller

I would like to access an `NSString` from Viewcontroller A when I am in view controller B

**IN VIEWCONTROLLER A .H**

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *test;
```

**IN VIEWCONTROLLER A .M**

```
@synthesize test;

// view did load

test = @"dikke bertha";
```

**IN VIEWCONTROLLER B .H**

```
#import "ViewcontrollerA.h"

@property (weak, nonatomic ) ViewcontrollerA *VCA
```

**IN VIEWCONTROLLER B .M**

```
synthesize VCA;

NSLog (@"%@", VCA.test )
```

THE NSLOG TURN NULL...

Comment: Do you create an instance of `ViewcontrollerA` and assign to the `VCA` property?

Comment: IT is because the property ViewcontrollerA *VCA is nil. You declared it but you didn't assign any instance of ViewControllerA.

Comment: @rmaddy-can we use singleton for this purpose , so that whenever we want an instance of the view controller, we can just to [VC sharedInstance] ?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Can you? Sure. Should you? Unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it so that your string appears in Class 2 as you have declared it in another class(Class 1), you need to make it so that initializing a Class 1 object also assigns a value to your string. For example.

ViewControllerA.h:

```
@interface ViewControllerA : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *test;
-(instancetype)init;
@end
```

ViewControllerA.m

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"

@interface ViewControllerA ()
@end

@implementation ViewControllerString

-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
      _test = @"Testing stuff";
    }
    return self;
}
```

ViewControllerB.h:

```
#import "ViewControllerA.h"
@interface ViewControllerB : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewControllerA *vcString;
@end
```

ViewControllerB.m:

```
#import "ViewControllerB.h"

@interface ViewControllerB ()
@end

@implementation ViewControllerB

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _vcString = [[ViewControllerA alloc]init];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.vcString.test);
}
```

When you create a specific initializer in ViewControllerA, it makes it so that whenever you do:

```
ViewControllerA *viewControllerAObject = [ViewControllerA alloc]init];
```

in another class, you make a ViewControllerA object that comes with a specific text string  when it is initialized.

Comment: This doesn't quite cover the OP's situation. They have a property for the other view controller. Update your answer to better match the question.

Comment: Okay - changed to be more specific. @rmaddy